# Trying to get property of non-object - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to make update form, that is going to retrieve the data for the specific ID selected, and fill in the form, so its going to be available for updating.

When I click edit on the specific entry (Product in my case), it takes me to the `edit_product_view`, but states the error **"Trying to get property of non-object"** for every variable that I use in `set_values` of the form elements.

Using `print_r`, I get the correct associative array, so it's passed correctly.

This is excerpt of my `edit_product_view`.

```
<h2><?php echo $heading; ?></h2>
<hr>
<table id="newproduct">
<?php echo form_open('products/edit/'.$product->id); ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo form_label('Name:');?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('prodname', set_value('prodname', $product->prodname));?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo form_label('Product Type:');?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('ptname_fk', $product_types, set_value('ptname_fk', $product->ptname_fk));?></td>
</tr>
```

`$product` is the array holding all the key-value pairs, but I cannot fill the form for some reason.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i may have been being thick and mistaken your question, let me know.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To access the elements in the array, use array notation: `$product['prodname']`

`$product->prodname` is object notation, which can only be used to access object attributes and methods.

Comment: Doesn't work. Here is the print_r output. 'Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [prodname] => Baked Fillo
            [base_unit] => 500.00
            [retail_price] => 50.00
            [alert_quantity] => 0.00
            [ptname_fk] => 1
            [pcname_fk] => 1
            [wname_fk] => 1
            [uname_fk] => 1
            [uname] => grams
            [pcname] => Fillo
            [ptname] => Finished Good
            [wname] => Finished Goods
        )
 
)'

Comment: Found a work around! Thank you!
I'm referencing the as
$product['0'] -> prodname;

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense based on the array dump.

Comment: I am using Laravel and this applies there too. Thanks a lot Orbit.

Answer (score 9):

To get the value:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
```

Then, for single row from(in controller):

```
$query1 = $query->row();
$data['product'] = $query1;
```

In view, you can use your own code (above code)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was looping through a series of objects from an XML file, but some of the instances apparently were not objects which was causing the error. Checking if the object was empty before processing it fixed the problem.

In other words, without checking if the object was empty, the script would error out on any empty object with the error as given below.

> Trying to get property of non-object

**For Example:**

```
if (!empty($this->xml_data->thing1->thing2))
{
   foreach ($this->xml_data->thing1->thing2 as $thing)
   {

   }
}
```