# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my site, user suppose to select a car brand, a model of that brand and an engine of that model. Eventually, after those selections year tabs appears and user selects a year so he/she can see specs of that car. But when I click one of year tabs "Trying to get property of non-object" error appears.

It's at my `car_model.php line 53` (Line 53 is the return line),

```
function getEngineId($engine){

    $this->db->where("engine",$engine);
    $query = $this->db->get("car_engine");
    $eId = $query->row();
    return $eId->id;
}
```

This is how tabs and contents(specs) of it filled.

```
public function populateTabs(){

    $this->load->model("car_model");
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $year = $this->input->post("year");
    $engine = $this->input->post("engine");

    if(isset($id, $year, $engine)){

        $eId = $this->car_model->getEngineId($engine);
        $years = $this->car_model->getYears($eId);
        $this->load->library("car");
        $car = new Car($id,$year);

        echo "<ul class='nav nav-tabs' id='yearTabs'>";

        foreach ($years->result() as $row){

            echo "<li class='first'><a href='#$id-$row->year' data-toggle='tab'>".$row->year."</a></li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";

        echo "<div class='tab-content'>";

        foreach ($years->result() as $row){

            echo "<div class='tab-pane fade in first' id='$id-$row->year'>";

       ...Irrevelant echo part...
 }
}
```

**UPDATE :** I checked `eId` by `var_dump()` and it echoes just what I wanted. If it returns false(obviously it is), shouldn't `var_dump()` prints "false"?

**UPDATE 2:** Before clicking a year tab there is no error.

Here is printing selected car name(title) and its years javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var brand = "";
var model = "";
var engine = "";
var bc = 0;
var mc = 0;
var title = document.getElementById("title");

$(".brand a").live('click',function(){

    brand = $(this).text();
    bc++;
    if(bc > 1){
        $(".mtr").collapse("hide");
    }
});

$(".model a").live('click',function(){

    model = $(this).text();
    mc++;
    if(mc > 1){
        $(".mtr").not("#"+model+"Motors").collapse("hide");
    }
});

$(".engine a").live('click',function(){

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        engine = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "populateTabs",
            data: "id=" + id + "&engine=" +engine,
            success: function(data){
                $("#tabs").html(data);
            }
        });

        if(brand == 'Bmw'){
            $(title).html(brand + " " + model + engine);
        }
        else{
            $(title).html(brand + " " + model+ " " + engine);
        }
 });
});
```

And here is after selecting a year javascript

```
$(".nav-tabs a").live('click', function(){

var year = $(this).text();

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "populateTabs",
    data: "year=" + year,
    success: function(data){
        $("#tabContent").html(data);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter ? It states you should use the array notation $eId['id'] instead of the object notation.

Comment: This gives "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error.

Comment: There is no error. It prints for example id="2-2013"

Comment: Can you include the var_dump() please?

Comment: `var_dump(null)` prints null, `var_dump(false)` prints false.

Comment: You're right. I changed my update. `var_dump()` prints what I want. Not false or null

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging it correctly? Observe that `getEngineId()` may not *always* fail, it should fail only for some inputs.

Comment: Also noticed you use $eId as identifier in your model and your (controller I guess), be specific to wich one you refer in comment/question anytime because can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Debug your AJAX call, check with the devTools maybe I missed but until now I didn't know you were using ajax.

Answer (score 2):

You are not handling errors properly. You expect `$eId` to be an object returned by `$query->row()`, but what if it fails? `$eId` is either `NULL` or a boolean `FALSE` and you are trying to read a property from it.

Answer (score 0):

`$eId` is probably `false` or `null` because `$query->row();` has failed. Check your return values.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're not getting results from your query.

from CI doc.

> Testing for Results
>
> If you run queries that might not produce a result, you are encouraged
>   to test for a result first using the num_rows() function:

Try:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{    
    $eId = $query->row();
    return $eId->id;
} else
{
  return false;//or something you can validate in your controller.
}
```

Comment: You're correct. When I do like this, loop returns false but how can it be possible? `$eId` is right, `var_dump($eId)` is giving what I wanted.

Comment: Can you post the var_dump () output for $eId in your questiobn ? did you var_dump() in the else block ? and does your code always fail ? and the post full error message, please.

Comment: Which loop ? Sorry I thing got confused.

Comment: Yes, I did it in the else loop. And the response is, <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre><ul class='nav nav-tabs' id='yearTabs'></ul><div class='tab-content'></div>

Comment: Well if went to the else part, you're not getting any result in your query and need to handle that in your controller.

Comment: I think i got results before clicking a year tab. When I click one of year tab then I get error.