# Codeigniter model "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Error**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/task_model.php

Line Number: 43

Backtrace:

File: C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\models\task_model.php
Line: 43
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\controllers\tasks.php
Line: 57
Function: get_project_name

File: C:\AppServ\www\ci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

**This model**

```php
<?php 

class Task_model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_task($task_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $task_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('tasks');

        return $query->row();

    }


    public function create_task($data){

        $query = $this->db->insert('tasks', $data);

        return $query;

    }


    public function get_task_project_id($task_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $task_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('tasks');

        return $query->row()->project_id;


    }


    public function get_project_name($project_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $project_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('projects');

        return $query->row()->project_name;
    }


    public function get_task_project_data($task_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $task_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('tasks');

        return $query->row();


    }


    public function edit_task($task_id, $data){

        $this->db->where('id', $task_id);

        $this->db->update('tasks', $data);

        return true;


    }



}

?>
```

**This Controller**

```html
<?php 

class Tasks extends CI_Controller{
 
 public function display($task_id){

  $data['task'] = $this->task_model->get_task($task_id);

  $data['main_view'] = "tasks/display";
  $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

 }


 public function create($project_id){

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('task_name', 'Task Name', 'trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('task_body', 'Task Description', 'trim|required');


  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   
   $data['main_view'] = 'tasks/create_task';
   $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

  }else{


   $data = array(

    'project_id' => $project_id,
    'task_name' => $this->input->post('task_name'),
    'task_body' => $this->input->post('task_body'),
    'due_date' => $this->input->post('due_date')
   );

   if ($this->task_model->create_task($data)) {
    
    $this->session->set_flashdata('task_created', 'Your task Has Been Created');
    redirect('tasks/index');

   }

  }

 }

 public function edit($task_id){

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('task_name', 'Task Name', 'trim|required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('task_body', 'Task Description', 'trim|required');


 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

  $data['project_id']   = $this->task_model->get_task_project_id($task_id);
  $data['project_name']  = $this->task_model->get_project_name($data['project_id']);
  $data['the_task']    = $this->task_model->get_task_project_data($task_id);
  
  $data['main_view'] = 'tasks/edit_task';
  $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);

 }else{

  $project_id = $this->task_model->get_task_project_id($task_id);


  $data = array(

   'project_id' => $project_id,
   'task_name'  => $this->input->post('task_name'),
   'task_body'  => $this->input->post('task_body'),
   'due_date'   => $this->input->post('due_date')
  );

  if ($this->task_model->edit_task($task_id, $data)) {
   
   $this->session->set_flashdata('task_updated', 'Your task Has Been Created');
   redirect('projects/index');

  }

 }

}

}


 ?>
```

I cannot find the problem :(

Comment: Just a tip if using codeigniter 3 > veirsions file names and class names should have first letter upper case Filename: models/task_model.php change to Filename: models/Task_model.php same applies with controllers

Answer (score 1):

You need to check row has data or not. Please replace the method by this method.

```html
    public function get_project_name($project_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $project_id);

        $query = $this->db->get('projects');

        $row= $query->row();
        if(isset($row)){
           return $row->project_name;
        }else{
           return "";
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

possible duplicate of this question [Trying to get property of non-object - CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter)

The way you get the result of the query on line 43 is not correct. You use an object notation where you need to use an array notation.

Try something like:

```
return $query['0']->project_name;
```

Comment: row() method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an object. No need to here add object notation. Here has not set data for this reason show error. Please see the link https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html