# How to get single row CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I get single row when I call "conversationID",

Right now when I call "conversationID = 0" it show all "conversationID" by 0

message table,

```
|ID|conversationID|from|to|
|1|0|3|4
|2|0|4|3
|3|0|3|4
|4|1|2|4
|5|1|4|2
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $conversations_inbox = $this->conversation_model->get_conversation_inbox($this->user->info->ID);
    $this->template->loadContent("conversations/index.php", array("conversations_inbox" =>  $conversations_inbox,)
    );
}
```

Model

```
public function get_conversation_inbox($userid) {
        $query = $this->db->where("conversations.from_user = ". $userid)->or_where("conversations.to_user = ". $userid)->select("*")->from("conversations")->join("conversation_message", "conversation_message.conversationID = conversations.conversationID")->order_by("conversation_message.date", "DESC")->get();
        return $query->row();
    }


<?php
foreach ($conversations_inbox as $c) { ?>
<li class="mail-starred">
    <div class="mail-from"><a href="<?php echo base_url("conversations/message/") . $c['conversationID'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . $c['store_picture'] ?>" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;margin-right: 10px;">
    <?php echo $c['store_name'] ?></a></div>
    <div class="mail-subject">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url("conversations/message/") . $c['conversationID'] ?>">Test</a>
    </div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `return $query->row();`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `$query->result()` which returns array of possible results, if you need only one record you should use `$query->row()`.

You can read more about returning result from documentation here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows

Comment: Get error Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You can access variable of array notation with ,  `$varName['fieldName']` and if it object : `$varName->fieldName` . check your output of `print_r($conversations_inbox)`. and use syntax accordingly. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter

Comment: Yes I get the output but how to foreach?

Comment: output is array or object?, please mark as answer and edit your question so I can help you.

Comment: the output is array,

Comment: then you need to access with `$varName['fieldName']` , in your current code you are using object notation.

Comment: Still not work,error Message:  Illegal string offset 'store_name'

<?php
foreach ($conversations_inbox as $c) { ?>
    <?php echo $c['store_name'] ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I Think as per question description `store_name` field is not available in table. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can get single row with array properties by:

```
$row = $query->row_array()
```

Then you can get properties by your table example:

```
if ($row) {
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['conversationID'];
    echo $row['from'];
    echo $row['to'];
}
```