# (Codeigniter) Why this error 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could you help me with this?

I don't have any code in my controller because I'm connecting directly to my model from my view

My model

```
public function getSeller($id){
    $row = $this->db->select('id_u, name_u, group_u')
                    ->from('u_users')
                    ->where('id_u', $id)
                    ->where('group_u', 2)
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->get()
                    ->row();
    return $row->name_u;
}
```

My view

```
<td><? echo $this->generals->getSeller($gQ['id_s']); ?></td>
```

Comment: please have a look on [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

Comment: Are you sure? If you have no code in your controller - how are you calling the view?

Comment: Indeed. Unless CI magically changed overnight you *cannot* render a view without a controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object - CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Well let's put in some debug code and see what is going on and document it... and add in the fixes.

Your issue is, for some id's you will not have a result as you expect! So you need to cater for the case which results in a NULL. How do we know this... Because we worked it out...

Here is the code I used. If any questions regarding this - just ask.

```
// Test conditions - Table entries
// We have an entry for id_u = 1, which has a group_u of 2
// We have an entry for id_u = 2, which has a group_u of 1

public function getSeller($id){
    $row = $this->db->select('id_u, name_u, group_u')
        ->from('u_users')
        ->where('id_u', $id)
        ->where('group_u', 2)
        ->limit(1)
        ->get()
        ->row();

    // Added next line for Debug
    var_dump($row); // What actually happens - Let's See!
    // From the var_dump we will get...
    //      null if no match was found - for $id = 2
    //
    //      OR ( as seen using var_dump ) - for $id = 1
    //
    //      object(stdClass)[19]
    //        public 'id_u' => string '1' (length=1)
    //        public 'name_u' => string 'Fred' (length=4)
    //        public 'group_u' => string '2' (length=1)

    // Did we actually get a result?
    if($row) {
        // Yep, so $row->name_u should exist
        return $row->name_u;
    } else {
        // Nope, so either return a string or a Boolean like FALSE or NULL
        return "Nothing Found";
    }
}
```

Technically

```
if($row) {
```

should be

```
if($row !== NULL) {
```

Which is testing for Equivalence and Type. But that's a discussion for another day.

Answer (score 0):

I really doesn't know that how can you load a view without controller. Please follow the proper way. In Your Model, Do like this:

```
public function get_attendance_by_id($attendance_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('attendance')
    ->where('attendance_id', $attendance_id)
    ->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Attendance_Model');
}

public function attendance_home($attendance_id)
{
    $data['attendance'] = $this->Attendance_Model->get_attendance_by_id($attendance_id);

    $this->load->view('attendance', $data);
}
```

In your View:

```
   <td><?= $attendance->username ?></td>
```