# How to solve message Trying to get property of none object

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm tryin to get data from my database but when i try it, it's error and have message Trying to get property of none object,

This is my Model--

```
public function select2($where="") {
    $data=$this->db->query('select sum(diskon) as diskon, count(jumlah) as jumlah, sum(harga_satuan) as harga from detail_t '.$where);

        return $data;
}
```

This is my Controller--

```
function konfirm() {

    $no_resi = $this->input->post('no_resi');

    $data_t = $this->m_barang->select2("where no_resi='$no_resi'")->result_array();

    $data = array(
           'no_resi'=>$no_resi,
           'diskon'=>$data_t->diskon,,
           'j_barang'=>$data_t->jumlah,
           'subtotal'=>$data_t->harga
            );

    $this->load->view('Main/check_out', $data);
}
```

I expect the output is data from my database when no_resi = $no_resi

Comment: This is the most common error I've seen on here. it has been addressed countless times. this question shows very little research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object - CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A lot of the time the first question someone asks is something that has been asked many times before, but new folks haven't learned their searching skills yet. The thing to understand is that SO is more about remembering the common questions and less about answering them over and over. In your case, you have tried to execute a query, but there was an error, so `$data` is `false`. There are already many questions here about how to find out what went wrong, and the CodeIgniter documentation also tells you how to understand the error.