# Problem displaying data in view file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with Codeigniter. I am unable to display data in view file. Given below is the code of my model, controller and view file. I have also attached a screenshot of the error for better clarity.

**Model**

```
public function get_projects ($userid = '')
 {
   if (empty($userid)){
     return FALSE;
   }
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('projects');
        $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->row_array();                 
 }
```

**Controller**

```
$uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $data['details']= $this->projects->get_projects($uid);
        $this->load->view('design/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('design/nav', $data);
        $this->load->view('content/dashboard', $data);
        $this->load->view('design/footer', $data);
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-6">
            <?php foreach ($details as $row){ echo $row->id; } ?>
        </div>
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried to check if it is an associative array instead? The `return $query->row_array();` Seeps that returns the data as an associative array.

Comment: And did it work or not? Is has not worked then update your question with your trial ;) . Also update the question showing the result of `var_dump($row);` furthermore in theese situations you can use a tool named `xdebug` as well.

Comment: it did not work. I also tried changing my model file to if($query->num_rows() == 1){
                    return $query->row();
                }else{
                    return $query->result();
                }

Comment: no luck. I think I have a really stupid mistake

Comment: On your view just place `var_dump($row)` on the first line of it from that figure out what type of variable is. (After you debugged it just remove it). About `var_dump()` look on [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: @AmanMishra from model returns `array` so try `echo $row['id'];` in `view`

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter Please Check:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175161/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-codeigniter

Comment: Amarat it is not a duplicate of that question. Please read the problem carefully. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the return of model function:
`return $query->row_array();` that returns only 1 array (or `return $query->row();` that also returns only 1 object). While you are iterating it in view.

Not sure about your purpose, but you can fix it by or:

- Do not use iteration in view, just use the variable `$details->id`
- Change your `return $query->row_array();` to `return $query->result();`

Comment: Yeah I found the problem and now understand it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it sounds like you want an *object* as you are using object notation `$row->id` and not `$row['id']`. This means you need to use `row()`. This also means since you will have 1 result, you don't need a `foreach`.

Model:

```
public function get_project($userid) {
   $q = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('userid', $userid));
   if ($q->num_rows() !== 1) {
       return false;
   }
   return $q->row();                 
 }
```

Controller:

```
$uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
if (empty($uid)) {
    show_error('user id not set'); // we probably shouldn't have gotten this far
}
$project = $this->projects->get_project($uid);
if ($project === FALSE) {
    show_error("no rows in project table for user with id: $uid");
}
$data['details'] = $project;
$this->load->view('design/header', $data);
$this->load->view('design/nav', $data);
$this->load->view('content/dashboard', $data);
$this->load->view('design/footer', $data);
```

View:

```
<p><?php echo $details->id; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $details->someothervar; ?></p>
```

While this code may not resolve your problem (I am guessing that there are either no projects for a user with that id or that the session `uid` is incorrectly set) it will help you debug things and it is good practice to always check for `num_rows()` and that your variables are outputting what you expect they are. I tend to keep *all* of these checks in the controller.

Comment: thanks Alex for your reply. I came to know some important things through this.

Answer (score 0):

In your view page change `$row->id;` to `$row['id']` it will generate result

```
<div class="col-6">
            <?php foreach ($details as $row){ echo $row['id']; } ?>
 </div>
```